# Splunk Summary Indexes - why does sistats not work like stats?

Tags: splunk

I have created a summary index. I am making use of "[`sistats count by <fields>`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/sistats)" to populate all the fields required. And I see those fields as well.

The issue is - On this index I am trying to use [`chart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/chart) command and also [`stats count(<field>) as test`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats) (`chart` command in one query and `stats count` in another query) but it's not working. There are no results returned. Instead, if I use the `stats` command and populate data to a summary index, both commands work.

Please let me know why `chart` and `stats` do not work on the summary index that I have created using `sistats`. [[`sichart`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/sichart) is also not working]. Am I missing some technical information here?

Answer (score 1):

When the `sistats` or `sichart` command is used to write to a summary index, the **exact same options** must be used in the corresponding `stats` or `chart`  command to read from the summary index.  This somewhat limits what you can do with your summary data.  Because of that and the issues you've experienced, most users avoid the si commands.